# How to present different ViewController after successful login

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, segue, viewcontroller

I am using Firebase as a back end and have coded the login part. When I login with a test account the debugger prints "Logged In:. However, when I try to go to the main view controller, I get the error "**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**" The code breaks on the line self.presentviewcontroller. What am doing wrong here?

```
 if email != "" && password != ""
    {
        FIREBASE_REF.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: {(error, FAuthData) -> Void in

            if error == nil
            {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(FAuthData.uid, forKey: "uid")

                print("logged in")
                self.logoutButton.hidden = false

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
                self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            else{
                print("The user was not logged in")
            }

        })
    }
    else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "ERROR", message: "Please Enter Email and Password", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check on your Main Storyboard that you set identifier `ViewController` to your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [`observeAuthEventWithBlock`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication) method, which listens for the authenticated state in realtime.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
  let ref = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")

  ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock({ authData in
    if authData != nil {
        // user authenticated
        print(authData)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginToOtherView", sender: nil)
    } else {
        // No user is signed in
    }
  })
}
```

You listen is `viewDidAppear`, so it continues to fire even if you go down the navigation stack.